# How can I get Eclipse on Linux to look more like on Windows?

Tags: linux, eclipse, windows, user-interface, themes

I like how Eclipse on Windows has a denser display of text in the workspace tree and some other windows and dialogs (and I kind of like Tahoma, too, although I'm not terribly attached to it). How can I get Linux Eclipse to look like that too?

Answer (score 0):

You can set various fonts (and colors) in the Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts.

For Eclipse Luna you can also edit the CSS files for the application (in Eclipse installation directory in the 'plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_xxxx/css' directory).